# Why was Integration needed

Tags: calculus, integration

Please answer the questions in number wise....

1. Before the invention of Integration, what was the cause for which this specific technique (Integration) was invented?
2. What difficulties can we face if there was no integration?
3. Where can it help us in the future?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. There are plenty of resources online to help you answer your first question. As for the second and third question, this is based on peoples opinions and guessing so they are not a good fit for this site. (Also, in general please try to ask one question at a time). You can find more information about how the site works in the Help Center: http://math.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: If there was no integration, we could not compute the area of a circle.

Comment: OK,  that's just one example of question 2.

Comment: The area of a circle was known long before integration. But integration makes finding the areas of various figures so much easier that even when there was a way to do it in earlier times, we tend to forget it.

Comment: @DavidK: Yes, the area of a circle was known long before a formal theory of integration was developed. However, even the most ancient derivations of the formula $A=\pi r^2$ are mathematically equivalent to integration: cut the circle up into finitely many pieces, approximate the sum of the areas of the pieces, and obtain the limiting value of the approximation as the number of pieces goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the area of a circle, namely $A=\pi r^2$, was known to the ancients. The procedure they used to justify this formula was basically the same method that we use today: cut the area into finitely many pieces, estimate the sum of the areas of the pieces, improve the estimate by letting the number of pieces get larger and larger, and find the limit. See for example [this proof](http://www.mathopenref.com/circleareaderive.html) of the formula $A=\pi r^2$.

The trouble is, the limits that you get by applying this procedure are not usually easy to evaluate **at all** (the circle area formula is an exception, the limit is pretty easy to evaluate in that case). Archimedes knew several more examples, but all of them are special cases.

The revolutionary advance discovered by Newton and Leibniz was that there is an alternate and completely general method (using "antiderivatives" or "indefinite integrals") to calculate the limits that you get from the above procedure (called "definite integrals"). That's exactly what the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us.

Comment: The main point, I think, is that the methods of Newton and Leibniz were called "the Calculus" because they provided such good _methods to calculate_ such things as the areas of regions enclosed by curves. Ancient mathematicians used some of the same _principles_: the area of a circle could be found by means of sequences of inscribed and circumscribed polygons, just as we might use upper and lower Riemannian sums; as you said, the revolutionary idea of the Calculus was to use an antiderivative to compute the area, which I think is very much unlike the ancient methods.